# How to partition correctly using the median of the first, middle, and last elements?

Tags: c++

My multiway_merge function is incorrect but not sure why. Seems to be correct logically but if the sorting is correct then it must be the merging. I am supposed to make a min heap of the first element of each sorted vector and then add them to the output_list in the correct sorted order and keep doing that until all the numbers have been added to the output_list.

```
int partition(vector<int>& list, int first, int last) {
    // The pivot should be the median of the
    // first, middle, and last elements.
    int middle = first + (last - first) / 2;

    if (list[first] > list[middle])
        swap(list[first], list[middle]);

    if (list[first] > list[last])       
        swap(list[first], list[last]);  

    if (list[middle] > list[last])
        swap(list[middle], list[last]);

    swap(list[middle], list[first]);            

    int pivot = list[first];
    int i = first - 1;
    int j = last + 1;

    while(true) {
        do {
            i++;
        } while(list[i] < pivot);

        do {
            j--;
        } while(list[j] > pivot);

        if(i >= j)                                  
            return j;

        swap(list[i], list[j]);
    }
}

void quicksort(vector<int>& list, int first, int last) {
    if(first < last) {
        int pivotLocation = partition(list, first, last);
        quicksort(list, first, pivotLocation);
        quicksort(list, pivotLocation + 1, last);
    }
}

void multiway_merge(vector<vector<int> >& input_lists, 
                    vector<int>& output_list) {

    int numLists = (int) (input_lists.size());
    int numElements = (int) (input_lists[0].size());
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> > minHeap;

    for(int i = 0; i < numLists; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numElements; j++) {
            minHeap.push(input_lists[i][j]);

            if (minHeap.size() > numLists) {
                output_list.push_back(minHeap.top());
                minHeap.pop();
            }
        }
    }

    while (minHeap.size()) {
        output_list.push_back(minHeap.top());
        minHeap.pop();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;

    vector<vector<int> > input_lists(n, vector<int>(m));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            cin >> input_lists[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Quicksort k sublists
    for (int i = 0; i < input_lists.size(); ++i)
        quicksort(input_lists[i], 0, m-1);

    // Merge n input sublists into one sorted list
    vector<int> output_list;
    multiway_merge(input_lists, output_list);

    for(int i = 0; i < output_list.size(); ++i)
        cout << output_list[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hoare's and Lomuto's algorithm: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hoares-vs-lomuto-partition-scheme-quicksort/

Comment: Why are those two if-statements necessary?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Oh, sorry forgot, we were told to swap the median of the first, middle, and last elements with the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any logical error with your `partition` function, Maybe your problem source is in the way that you call this function from `sort` function and you didn't share that function with us so I had to guess.

Anyway, using your implementation of `partition` function the quick sort algorithm would be something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> 


int partition(std::vector<int> &vec, int low, int high)
{
    int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;

    if((vec.at(middle) >= vec.at(low) && vec.at(middle) <= vec.at(high))
        || (vec.at(middle) <= vec.at(low) && vec.at(middle) >= vec.at(high)))
        std::swap(vec.at(high), vec.at(middle));

    if((vec.at(high) >= vec.at(low) && vec.at(high) <= vec.at(middle))
        || (vec.at(high) <= vec.at(low) && vec.at(high) >= vec.at(middle)))
        std::swap(vec.at(low), vec.at(high));


    int pivot = vec.at(low);
    int i = low - 1, j = high + 1;

    while(true)
    {
        do
        {
            i++;
        } while(vec.at(i) < pivot);

        do
        {
            j--;
        } while(vec.at(j) > pivot);

        if(i >= j)
            return j;

        std::swap(vec.at(i), vec.at(j));
    }
}

void quickSort(std::vector<int> &vec, int low, int high)
{
    if(low < high)
    {
        int pi = partition(vec, low, high);
        quickSort(vec, low, pi);
        quickSort(vec, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> input = {10, 7, 15, 9, 1, 33};
    quickSort(input, 0, input.size() - 1);

    for(auto iter = input.begin(); iter != input.end(); ++iter)
        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT :** Your quick sort wasn't the source of the problem, You have problem merging sorted vectors, so the source of the problem is in logic of your `multiway_merge` function.

You used `priority_queue` to achieve this merge and it's a valid approach, but I think you miss understood how `priority_queue` actually works.

you can enqueue as many elements you want but the order of outgoing elements are determined by the way you set your priority. Take a loot at [`priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Your compare condition to determine priority is right too, I mean using `greater<int>`. So the only problem in your code is one extra condition that you don't need it at all. I mean these lines of code :

```
if(minHeap.size() > numLists)
{
    output_list.push_back(minHeap.top());
    minHeap.pop();
}
```

Remove this condition and your `multiway_merge` will work fine. The final implementation of this function would be :

```
void multiway_merge(vector<vector<int> >& input_lists,
    vector<int>& output_list)
{

    unsigned int numLists = (int)(input_lists.size());
    int numElements = (int)(input_lists[0].size());
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int> > minHeap;

    for(int i = 0; i < numLists; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < numElements; j++)
        {
            minHeap.push(input_lists[i][j]);
        }
    }

    while(minHeap.size())
    {
        output_list.push_back(minHeap.top());
        minHeap.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what my quick sort function looks like as well. @Hamed

Comment: @JordanWard Then could you please sent your test input that works wrong?

Comment: Yes the input we are given to use to test is: {100, 28, 83, 22, 3, 4, 1, 0, 222, 425, 42, 49, 599, 58, 79, 934, 41, 23, 444, 422} @Hamed

Comment: I have deleted the other answer and edited this question. I would really appreciate the help, I have been working on this for a week and it is due in less than an hour now. Hopefully I can get this working, thanks!

Comment: Ahhhh! I see, that was dumb of me. Thank you so much! @Hamed

Comment: @JordanWard You are most welcome, just two things, first please **always** post the full and exact problem description so that one can help you quickly and second, consider marking this as answer and upvote if it helped you. cheers.

Comment: Sorry I feel I usually get downvotes because I share too much haha. I will try to get better at this. I will mark it as the answer and upvote it. Thank you again! @Hamed

Comment: @JordanWard people using their downvotes too much here, most of the time it's not even necessary or fair but one should ask question properly to get the answer, for the start you can take a look at these subjects [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @JordanWard BTW I didn't mean share *every thing*, I meant you should debug your program, spot the source of problem, try to solve it many times and after that if non of your approaches worked post it as question and be specific about it. Good luck